# CHANGE 0,0 from SVG

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG object (`<svg>`) in my HTML code and the coordinates 0,0 is at the leftmost and topmost of the element. How can I make the 0,0 be the leftmost and bottommost of the element without doing any other change to my code, only changing the attributes/style of SVG element?

CODE:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 15000 15000">...[HERE COMES THE VECTOR CONTENT]...</svg>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You could transform but if you've got any text it will appear upside down. The bottom line is that you're probably best sticking with the existing coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the contents of your SVG with a group that has a `transform` applied.  The transform should be a scale of -1 in the Y direction (to flip vertically) and a translate to move the flipped content back on screen.

However be aware, as Robert said, that some elements like text and images will now end up upside down.  So if you need to use those elements, you will need to aaply a transform on those to flip them back up the right way.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 300">
  <g transform="translate(0,300) scale(1,-1)">

    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#f8f8ff"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="5"/>
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your code is great but the coordinates of the elements will still remain the same. I am accessing those coordinates using JS to change graphics and flippin does not solve this. It would be much easier if it would be possible to change the origin. Any way, I will accept your answer as no one answered. Thank you so much Paul

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Any coordinates inside the `<g>` will now beahve as if the origin is at the bottom left and increase up and to the right. Just like normal cartesian coordinates.